# Invisible files/folders

Tags: files, directory, filemanager

I cannot see some files and folders. I know they are not flagged as hidden. I have show hidden file enabled and used `ls -a`.

I know they are there because I can use commands like `cd` (in terminal) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (file manager) to access or navigate to them if I know their name.

How do I force them to be visible?

Comment: Add examples and results of the commands and an `ls -lta` before and after please.